# Can't get directory listing on my Apache to work

Tags: apache2

I'm having trouble enabling the directory listing on apache. I did it a few weeks ago but had to reinstall cause my Wubi ran out of space, and now I can't get it to work and it's driving me crazy.

I have a folder /home/joon/Dropbox/Projects/apache, which I want to set as the root for my apache. Here's the first lines of the 'default' file in the sites-available folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /home/joon/Dropbox/Projects/apache
<Directory /home/joon/Dropbox/Projects/apache>
    Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
```

The rest is unchanged. Ports.conf is set to Listen 8888.
I thought the +Indexes should do it, but I must have overlooked something.

I get a 403, forbidden. "You don't have permission to access / on this server." 
If I input the url of an image, http://127.0.0.1:8888/joon/bin/1chart.png, it displays, but no directory listing.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '+' symbol before 'Indexes' is not needed.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Will suffice.

Comment: what the... I'm so sure I tried that first. Now I feel stupid. Anyway, it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, I get the directory listing, but when I click one of the directories that has an index.php or index.html, Chromium downloads that page instead of serving it. If I navigate to the index.php page it displays however. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the same result for all browser or just for chromium?.

Comment: it should be the same result across all internet browsers.

Comment: it's acting super weird. From my virtualbox I can access the apache server and it displays as expected, but locally I get downloads instead of displayed pages. I'll open up a new question if the issue persists...